# send form details to a mail as well as store in database(mysql) in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, email, phpmailer

I want to implement a feature on form submission It should be able to mail  as well It should be stored in Database simultaneously(mail will send both mail id which is specified in form as well as website email).Before asking here I made some of the research but I can find both action individually.I am able to save in Database not able to send mail getting error as **SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: (0).** For sending a mail I am using PHP mailer. please provide me some guidelines to do it.
code I tried So Far:

```
//database connection
  <?php include_once"config.php"; ?>
  <?php



   use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
   include_once "PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php";
   include_once "PHPMailer/Exception.php";
   include_once "PHPMailer/SMTP.php";

    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {

    $fname = $_POST['fname'];
    $lname = $_POST['lname'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];

        $query = "INSERT INTO mail_db(first_name,last_name,email) VALUES 
      ('$fname','$lname','$email');";

         $result= mysqli_query($connection,$query);

             // print_r($result);

    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
    $mail->Host = "mail.website.com";
    $mail->Port = 465;
    $mail->Username = 'sender@website.com';
    $mail->Password ='mypassword';
    $mail->setFrom("sender@website.com");
    $mail->Subject = 'testForm';
    $mail->addAddress("$email");
$mail->Body =
                "FirstName"."$fname"."\n".
                "LasttName"."$lname"."\n".
                "email"."$email"."\n";

 $mail->send();
 $mail->clearAddresses();
 $mail->addAddress("recieve@website.com");
 $mail->Body = 'New Registration Details'."\n".

                "FirstName"."$fname"."\n".
                "LasttName"."$lname"."\n".
                "email"."$email"."\n";


 $mail->send();


if($mail->send()){

header("Location: thanks.html");
}
else{
    echo $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
```

}

?>

Comment: You're calling `send` three times in total, so you'll send two copies of the second message. Aside from that, read the PHPMailer troubleshooting guide, which describes how to diagnose and remedy connection problems; it's very likely that your ISP blocks outbound SMTP.

Comment: @ Synchro Thank You for Replay problem got resolved